# Dynamic mongodb query generation with Node.js driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using the Node.js driver for MongoDB and have no trouble constructing query objects outside of the call to find() until I attempt to introduce an `$or` construct into the mix.

I am attempting to dynamically generate the query because I have a variable number of parameters and would prefer to NOT have as many calls to collection.find as I have parameters.

To that end I am using a query as simple as:

```
var query = {};
query['name'] = 'Steve';
query['date_created'] = '<some date>';

mongo_collection.find(query, function(err, c) {});
```

However, when I attempt to use $or the whole process falls apart.

I have tried each of the following with no joy:

```
var query = {};
```

1.

```
query[$or] = [ { 'field' : 'value1' }, { 'field' : 'value2' } ];
query['date_created'] = '<some date>';
```

2.

```
query = { $or : [ { 'field' : 'value1' }, { 'field' : 'value2' } ] };
query['date_created'] = '<some date>';
```

3.

```
query = eval("[ { 'field' : 'value1' }, { 'field' : 'value2' } ]");
query['date_created'] = '<some date>';
```

In every case the `$or` is wrapped in quotes (honestly I am not sure if this is the problem or not...) and the query fails.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: does it throwing an error or is it just not returning any data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how you can do it (there are probably multiple ways):

```
var query = {};

query["$or"]=[];
query["$or"].push({"field":"value1"});
query["$or"].push({"field":"value2"});
query["date_created"]="whatever";

query
{
    "$or" : [
        {
            "field" : "value1"
        },
        {
            "field" : "value2"
        }
    ],
    "date_created" : "whatever"
}
```

Now you should be able to run db.collection.find(query)